# How to refresh a subscriber

Tags: angular

on ngInit I create a subscriber something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getData(param1)
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
        })
    );
}
```

then how do I do a refresh if I need to use e.g. param2 in getData()?
I.e. user click a button and gets the data for param2. I don't think I need to unsubscribe and then subscribe again. Is there any other feasible way to refresh? Sorry for dummy question, I'm new with Angular. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like getData is a function, not sure if it returns an observable

But if you subscribe to an observable in a service, say 
(inside you service)

```
data: string[] = []
listChanged = new Subject<string[]>
```

(inside your component)

```
this.myService.listChanged
 .subscribe(data => { this.data = data})
```

then everytime some components updates it with
(inside you service)

```
addDate() {
 data.push('some string');
 listChanged.next(this.data);
}
```

You can use `.next` method on subject to cause all subscribers to fetch new data in their callback function

Answer (score 0):

Another way to the @Iancovici solution is to use [BehaviorSubject](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md)

Here's how you can create a service.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class myService {
  private userData = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({}); //user proper datatype
  getData= this.userData.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeUserData(userData: any) {
    this.userData.next(userData);
  }
}
```

And in the onClick() methis of the button call:

```
changeUserData(userData);
```